# Multiple flag dialogs for posts can be opened with the keyboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dialog

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a post.
2. Click on **flag** using the mouse.
3. Wait for a few seconds to avoid the rate limit.
4. Press Enter.
5. Repeat from 3.

Expected result: there is a single flag dialog on the screen.

Actual result: You can open many [image: You can open many]

The flag dialogs are initially stacked exactly on top of each other, so you have to drag one to the side and see the rest underneath.

It's happening cross-site. Tested Stack Overflow (first screenshot) and [here is Meta Stack Exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQmz.png).

This happens for both questions and answers. As far as I can see, it is everywhere a flag dialog for a post can be opened from. For example [here is the same dialog from a review queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ahyw.png).

Alternative way to trigger the same behaviour using the keyboard shortcuts:

1. Open a post.
2. Using keyboard shortcuts - press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for **m**oderate
3. Press <kbd>f</kbd> for **f**lag
4. Click somewhere within the dialog (clicking outside will close the dialog)
5. Interacting using the mouse will close the keyboard shortcut menu.
6. Repeat from 2.

Additional information:

Clicking on **flag** using the mouse will close all dialogs and open a new one.

The behaviour is inconsistent with the close dialog - doing the same steps for it will leave a single dialog open on the screen.

- Opening a flag dialog first and a close dialog afterwards will leave just the close dialog.
- Opening a close dialog first and a flag dialog afterwards will leave both dialogs on the screen.

Tested in Firefox 77 and Chrome 75 on Windows 10.

Comment: I cannot repro on Chrome or FF. Can anyone else repro this?

Comment: @YaakovEllis tried it again and it still works. The easiest way is click on **flag** using the mouse -> wait for 5 seconds -> hit enter. You'd have two flag dialogs but they are stacked on top of each other - I had to drag them to separate them for the screenshots, otherwise it looks like a single one.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Didn't realize that they were stacked.

Comment: @YaakovEllis yes, I added the info to the question. I realised it's missing.

Comment: Let them reproduce... ;)

Comment: Coming back to this: the bug has been added to our list to address. Will have more updates here when we get to it.

Comment: Can you multiflag?

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein no, if you choose one option on one dialog, all of them close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed.

Opening a new flag or close dialog will dismiss the existing one, similar to what was being done for the close dialog.  Some hidden complexity here is that you can open the close dialog from the flag dialog and we have a dance where we open the close dialog but keep the flag dialog around and we switch back if you click "back", but I got that sorted out.