# Bounty modal window progress is lost when clicking "share" on an answer

Tags: bug, user-interface, bounty-dialog

I had an unfortunate experience trying to start a bounty.

I chose "Reward existing answer" and typed out a custom message explaining why it deserves a bounty. Wanting to link the answer in the bounty message, I scrolled down to it and clicked "share" to copy the link to it. This closed the bounty pop-up, which meant I lost my message and had to redo starting the bounty.

I'm not sure if this behavior is intended -- it seems only one bounty/share pop-up window can appear at a time. But from a user view, this seems unexpected and likely to cause wasted effort.

Comment: Got nothing to do with the share button... the issue is that the bounty dialog does not "remember" you last activity in it.

Comment: As Shadow said, the bounty dialog will close if you click on any area of the page (outside the dialog itself); not necessarily on the share button.

Comment: This is not specific to the bounty dialog and it’s not specific to the share button. If you open _any_ dialog and click outside of it _anywhere_, all open dialogs will close. _“it seems only one bounty/share pop-up window can appear at a time”_ — that’s also not relevant: it’s about _clicks_ inside or outside a pop-up or dialog. With `Tab` or `Shift`+`Tab` and `Enter` you can open dialogs without closing popups — [even multiple dialogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349919/289905).

Comment: @user289905 it's about preserving the state of the dialogs. As a user, I would expect the dialog to preserve its state when closed, unless it was closed via "Cancel" button, which isn't the case in SE dialogs. It's not really a bug, but prefer to leave it for the developers to decide.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask So this is more a [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @user289905 tricky. From UX point of view, it's a bug. From pure development point of view, a feature request. So technically a feature request.

Comment: related / similar issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402199/too-easy-to-lose-custom-flag-message?noredirect=1#comment803234_402199